# JLabel wont save through the JTextPane

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextpane

I was trying to save the JTextPane which has the JLabel on it through `insertComponent` but by the time I want to save the JTextPane through filewriter and Buffered write on the textfile JLabel wont show up

Here is the result inside the text file:

```
 : asdasd
 : adasddasdasdsd
 : asdasda
 : asd
 : asd
 : asd
 : as
 : daaa
 : sdas
 : das
 : d
```

Here is the code that I write:

```
 BufferedWriter save = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempfile));

             jtep.write(save);
```

This is where text are taken from the database. I will jump to the result:

```
while(rs.next())
        {

            try {
                final JLabel jp = new JLabel(rs.getString("username")+ "\n");
                jp.setAlignmentY(0.75f);
                final String usernameChat = rs.getString("username");
                jp.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        Cursor c = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                        jp.setCursor(c);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){System.out.print("lawl");}
                        if(e.getClickCount() == 2)new OneToOneChat(usernameChat);


                        jp.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    jp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

                    }

                });
                jp.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,16));
                jtep.insertComponent(jp);
                StyleConstants.setForeground(MainPanel.sas2, Color.BLACK);
                MainPanel.sd.insertString(MainPanel.sd.getLength(), ": ", MainPanel.sas2);
                StyleConstants.setForeground(MainPanel.sas,new Color(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("color"))));
                sd.insertString(sd.getLength(),rs.getString("message")+ "\n", MainPanel.sas);
```

The result in the java:

```
kev : adasddasdasdsd
kev  : asdasda
kev  : asd
kev  : asd
kev  : asd
kev  : as
kev  : daaa
kev  : sdas
kev  : das
kev  : d
```

Why is that JLabel wont show up in textfile and is there a way on doing it?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that JLabel wont show up in textfile

What exactly did you expect to show up?  A text file contains text.  A `JLabel` is **not text**.

If you want the text *inside* the label to be written to file, you'll need to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are lacking much...
Text files are meant to store text information. Text editors(in general) don't display anything except text. If you really want to store retrieve JLabel, store the information of JLabel in a text file and use your own program to decode it to display the JLabels back.

If you want to store the information of JLabel objects, you may use java serialization to write into file and use the same concept to retrieve back.

All the best.